# How to get Coveralls code coverage for a Swift project

Tags: swift, code-coverage, travis-ci, coveralls

I have code coverage reporting set up on Travis-CI with the help of a ruby script it once wrote.

See for example: https://travis-ci.org/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText at the bottom of the log.

I have started a new open source project Kvitto and set it up on Travis-CI here: https://travis-ci.org/Cocoanetics/Kvitto

I need help how to get coverage to appear on Coveralls here: https://coveralls.io/github/Cocoanetics/Kvitto - right now there is no coverage info for anything.

I am building with a build configuration "Coverage" where I have set up both the legacy as well as the new style... do I need to adapt the ruby script ([link](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/Kvitto/blob/develop/coveralls.rb)) in a way to collect the `.gcda` files correctly?

Comment: Codecov, an alternative to Coveralls provides support for Swift. Learn more at https://github.com/codecov/example-swift

Comment: What's the difference between the implementation mentioned on the URL you gave and https://github.com/codecov/codecov-python ?

Comment: The only difference is the language of the uploader. Bash vs Python. Some CI providers on OSX systems cannot install Python.